# Renew iOS developer certificates

Tags: xcode, certificate

After expiring of the Apple Worldwide Developer Certificate I've installed the new AppleWWDRCA certificate.

My Developer and Distribution certificates still say, the signing authority is not valid.

In Xcode preferences/accounts there are Reset buttons next to this Signing Identities. When I click on Reset, the buttons are grayed out but nothing happens. The certificates stay invalid.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I had made all things correct, but I've overseen one important:

In Keychain Access, System, Certificates -- View: Show expired certificates
Then delete all expired certificates.

Answer (score 0):

If it expired then you have recreate it.